# Trying to create Singly Link List of random choice

Tags: c++

What is wrong in my code? I am getting stuck in an infinite loop.

```
void createList(sLL ** head, int n)
{
    cout<<"\nstart n :"<< n;

    if(n == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    sLL * temp = (sLL *) malloc(sizeof(sLL));
    if(temp != NULL)
    {
        temp->data = rand() % 100;
        temp->next = NULL;
        *head = temp;
        cout<<"\nI am thhere : "<<n;
        createList(&(temp->next), n - 1);
        cout<<"\nI am here : "<<n;
    }
}
```

Comment: When working with recursive functions you need to specify a case where the next call in the chain is skipped. For example, I have now added 20 entries to the chain, time to stop. What you're doing right now is just adding to the chain untill you run out of memory.

Comment: What sort of output are you getting from the code above?  You say infinite loop, but how are you sure?  You might add `<< endl` to each of your `cout` lines to defeat line-buffering and display each message on its own line.  It could be that your code is correct...

Comment: @RobinAbony : Then what does the `if (n == 0) return;` at the top do?

Comment: what are the initial arguments you call `createList` with?

Comment: The code works for me as-is. The only way I can see of causing an infinite loop is if you pass a negative value in for `n`.

Comment: Enter the number of nodes :7

start n :7
I am thhere : 7
start n :6
I am thhere : 6
start n :5
I am thhere : 5
start n :4
I am thhere : 4
start n :3
I am thhere : 3
start n :2
I am thhere : 2
start n :1
I am thhere : 1
start n :0
I am here : 1
I am here : 2
I am here : 3
I am here : 4
I am here : 5
I am here : 6

*****It gets stuck here *****

Comment: I'm with Peter.  Your list management code looks correct as-is.  Show us why you think you have an infinite loop.  Now, you could use `endl` on your `cout` lines to make it clearer what's going on.

Comment: @saurabh : That could just be an output flushing issue. `cout` is buffered by default, and so you may have printed your last message, but it won't be displayed.  `<< endl` or `<< flush` will flush the output, or adding a line `cout.flush()` will flush the output.

Comment: That output is consistent with the implementation. It doesn't seem that you are stuck, you output all the strings. Which additional outputs do you expect?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic :  Why do you say that?  I get that message on my side when testing.  I did have to add `endl` to my code to see all the messages.

Comment: @JoeZ Ignore it, I should have looked more carefully :)

Comment: If you are trying to learn C++, stop using `malloc` and use `new` instead, and try out a reference to a pointer instead of a pointer to a pointer. Makes the code a lot cleaner.

Comment: @crashmstr : Or just use `std::list`.  I suspect, though, this is for a class and the professor / teacher has very specific (and horrifying) requirements to use `malloc()`.

Comment: Does the function have to be recursive? Recursion for a single linked list is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list generation code looks correct.  Your output is buffered, though, so where you think your *code* is stuck it is not actually stuck.  Rather, your *messages* are stuck in the `cout` buffering.

Modify your `cout` messages to either `flush` the `cout` stream.  I've demonstrated each of the techniques below:

```
void createList(sLL ** head, int n)
{
    cout<<"\nstart n :"<< n << endl;  // endl operator flushes stream and gives a line break

    if(n == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    sLL * temp = (sLL *) malloc(sizeof(sLL));
    if(temp != NULL)
    {
        temp->data = rand() % 100;
        temp->next = NULL;
        *head = temp;
        cout<<"\nI am thhere : " << n << flush;  // flush operator flushes the stream without an added line break
        createList(&(temp->next), n - 1);
        cout<<"\nI am here : "<<n;
        cout.flush();   // alternately, you can flush cout directly.  Also does not add a line break
    }
}
```

If your code hangs, it is sometime after the `createList()` call in code you have not shown us.  But, because `cout` buffers its messages and because you have not flushed `cout`, you're being misled in your debugging efforts.

Comment: Ok Joe I tried endl and flush. My program continues for a small time. List gets created and again the next part of the code hangs. I would like to know in detail why I am facing the issue and what is the permanent solution for it or to tackle this. I have been making several program I am facing this issue first time.. So I am very confused... Want to dig deep into it so that i never face the issue again and have the knowledge to tackle it..

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere.  Perhaps close this question, since it's been answered.  You're now closer to the _real_ bug, so your debugging will be more fruitful hopefully.  If you get stuck debugging the actual bug, come back to us with a new question.  :-)  Glad to help!

Comment: Without seeing how the list gets used, I really have nothing direct to suggest on why the code down-stream might be hanging.  The code above does succeed at creating a singly-linked list.  If you're trying to traverse the linked list after you create it, make sure you're not modifying the list's `next` pointers as you walk the list.  You want to use temporary variables for your list traversal and only copy pointers out of the structures.  If you have an `&` anywhere in your list traversal, I'd be very suspicious.